# AngularJS - Access filtered data in another div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a filter applied for search feature where in user types search query in a text box and the results in ng-repeat get filtered. The code that I have is:

```
<div class="number-results">xxxxxx results found</div>
    <div ng-repeat="product in products | topProductsSearchFilter:searchData" class='top-product-icon' ng-click="productClicked(product)">
        <img class='top-product-icon-img' ng-src="{{product.thumbnail}}">
        <div class='top-product-icon-title' ng-bind="product.title"></div>
    </div>
```

As you can see I have invoked filter in ng-repeat: `topProductsSearchFilter:searchData`

searchData is the ng-model of search text box:

```
<input ng-model="searchData" type="text"/>
```

The filter that I have written results a JSON array of type Products. In the html I want to show the number of results returned by filter in this div:

```
<div class="number-results">xxxxxx results found</div>
```

My problem is how to best access the length of that JSON array outside of ng-repeat div tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a filtered list / alias right in the `ng-repeat` expression and get its length:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | someFilter)">
  {{item}}
</div>
<div>number of results: {{filteredItems.length}} out of {{items.length}}</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `item in items | someFilter as filteredItems`

Comment: @Phil, yes, in 1.3+, but it is still more limited (I think) since this approach could be used for intermediate filtered results (when there are multiple filters) whereas `as` cannot

Comment: That's a fair call. I'd never thought to assign only some filtered parts to a variable but I can see how that could be handy